# MATLAB: How to calculate (on) Submatrices without a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, submatrix

I want to split a matrix columnwise into 3 segments and do a calculation on it (`mean()`). Is there a way to get this without a for-loop, as I did in this provided sample?

```
M = [2 4 9; 50 50 200; 30 0 0];
M = [M 10*M]
N = length(M);
seg = 3 % split in lets say 3 parts
segLen = round(N/seg)
segBeg = (((1:seg)-1) * segLen)+1  % start indices
segEnd = segBeg + segLen -1        % end indices

for i = 1: length(segBeg)
    mean(M(:,segBeg(i):segEnd(i)),2)
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `blockproc` can be a solution here.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin "`help blockproc`

blockproc not found." I guess not everyone has that toolbox. ;-)

Comment: Good to know about `blockproc`. But I "only" own the Toolboxes DSP and Signal Processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think outside the box: use the 3rd dimension:

```
r=reshape(M,size(M,1),segLen,[])
squeeze(mean(r,2))
```

The first line produces a 3d array with the first matrix at `r(:,:,1)`, the second at `r(:,:,2)`, ... (use `M(:,1:seg*segLen)` instread of `M` if the number of columns is not divisible by `segLen`).
`mean(r,2)` produces a nrows-by-1-by-`seg` array, `squeeze` makes a nrows-by-`seg` matrix out of it again.

Comment: thank you very much! This is nice an elegant. Didn´t know about those commands.
I´ll use the `M(:,1:seg*segLen)` indexing, because the columns are not divisible everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) together with [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

```
result = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) mean(M(:,x:y),2), segBeg, segEnd,...
   'UniformOutput', false))
```

This results in

```
result =

   1.0e+03 *

    0.0030    0.0145    0.0650
    0.0500    0.3500    1.2500
    0.0150    0.1500         0
```

where each column represents the mean across one submatrix.

Another solution using [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) (like suggested by @DennisJaheruddin in the comments) could look like this

```
myFun = @(x) mean(x.data,2);

result2 = blockproc(M, [N, segLen], myFun)
```

This also results in

```
result2 =

   1.0e+03 *

    0.0030    0.0145    0.0650
    0.0500    0.3500    1.2500
    0.0150    0.1500         0
```

Note that `blockproc` can take advantage of parallel processing if the flag `'UseParallel'` is set to `true`, i.e., `result2 = blockproc(M, [N, segLen], myFun, 'UseParallel', true)`

Comment: Thanks @H.Muster, this usage of anonymous functions is also very nice! Didn´t use this in the past. But now I will. Is there any advantages/disadvantages compared to the `reshape`-method?

Comment: Actually, I do not know. The `reshape` solution seems simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can do for your example case

```
mean1 = mean(M(:,1:segLen))
mean2 = mean(M(:,segLen+1:N-segLen-1))
mean3 = mean(M(:,N-segLen:end))
```

Comment: I'm not sure this approach, while satisfying OP's immediate requirements, would scale well to an array with, say, 10^6 columns and 10^5 segments.